# Cannot send mails through fowarding mail

Tags: postfix, email-server

I am using a OSX with Server App who bring a Mail service that have Postfix and Dovecot.

Now i am unable to send mails in my mail server, i am getting this error:

```
EF5CBCF65F      992 Thu Nov  3 11:49:28  teste@X.pt
(connect to remote.X.pt[<IP>]:25: Connection refused)
                                        X@gmail.com
```

And all my mails are being stack as i have notice through mailq.

After trying telnet, i notice that i was only able to connect to localhost, 127.0.0.1 and remote.X.pt, was not able to be seen from outside. I have an Static IP that is not blocked (I already check from a huge list i just have 1 block).

In Postfix `main.cf` i have my interfaces to all:

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

Then i made a dig mx and i receive this:

```
<<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mx remote.X.pt
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11055
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;;remote.X.pt. IN MX
;; ANSWER SECTION:
remote.X.pt. 10800 IN MX0 remote.X.pt.
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
remote.X.pt. 10800 IN NS remote.X.pt.
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
remote.X.pt. 10800 IN A 192.168.1.1
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov  3 12:42:21 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 81
```

I already saw some fix's but till now no one have worked here, and i already add my server at DMZ just to see if was from the firewall, but it wasnt.

I am able to send mail from my local server without any outgoing mail, but if i use the same email on my mail server and my Mail app (client), it will goes to my ISP server without problem (right now i am getting an 550 error but at least i know that its there).

When i use another account just for forwarding mail purpose i receive that error of service. So how can i create an forwarding mail?

I have already search about it before but dont know how to set one, to use it to forward mails from local emails, to an external ISP mail server.

Any clue on how can i set and use a forwarding mail?

**Sven thanks for the edit of my post i didnt notice!**

Comment: After running netstat -tnlp tcp | grep './25 ' i notice that there was no output, but i am able to connect to that port through localhost, 127.0.0.1 or remote.X.pt. And it doesnt seem to be blocked by firewall after i add it at DMZ.

Comment: I am able to send mail from my local server without any outgoing mail, but if i use the same email on my mail server and my Mail app (client), it will goes to my ISP server without problem (right now i am getting an 550 error but at least i know that its there). When i use another account just for forwarding mail purpose i receive that error of service. So how can i create an forwarding mail? I have already search about it before but dont know how to set one, to use it to forward mails through from local emails, to an external ISP mail server.